# I'm confused on getters and returns in classes?

Tags: java, return, getter

I've been teaching myself coding, and getters and return values, and how to call upon them in the main program. To give it a go, I tried to write a program to calculate the cost of long distance calls, but it crashes right when I run it, and I know it has something to do with the class.

Fair warning, my time is a bit weird for calculating AM/PM but I did my best.

I think it has to be something with calling upon the calculations in my main code-- specifically the String weekday = call1.calculateweekday(); and int time = call1.calculatetime(); , but I'm very new to programming and I am very much just starting out and learning these terms and uses, so I've no idea what. I just know, when i move these two lines around my main program, it breaks at that point.

```
package practice;

import java.util.Scanner;

class Call {
    String weekdayinput;
    String weekday;
    int hour;
    String ampm;
    int time;

    int calculatetime() {

        if (ampm.equals("pm") || ampm.equals("PM") || ampm.equals("Pm")) {

            time = hour + 1200;
        } else if (ampm.equals("am") || ampm.equals("AM") || ampm.equals("Am")) {

            time = hour;

        }

        else {
            System.out.println("You entered something either time or AM/PM incorrectly.");
        }

        return time;
    }

    String calculateweekday() {

        if (weekdayinput.equals("mo") || weekdayinput.equals("Mo") || weekdayinput.equals("MO")) {

            weekday = "Monday";
        }

        else if (weekdayinput.equals("tu") || weekdayinput.equals("Tu") || weekdayinput.equals("TU")) {

            weekday = "Tuesday";
        }

        else if (weekdayinput.equals("we") || weekdayinput.equals("We") || weekdayinput.equals("WE")) {

            weekday = "Wednesday";
        }

        else if (weekdayinput.equals("th") || weekdayinput.equals("Th") || weekdayinput.equals("TH")) {

            weekday = "Thursday";
        }

        else if (weekdayinput.equals("fr") || weekdayinput.equals("Fr") || weekdayinput.equals("FR")) {

            weekday = "Friday";
        }

        else if (weekdayinput.equals("sa") || weekdayinput.equals("Sa") || weekdayinput.equals("SA")) {

            weekday = "Saturday";
        }

        else if (weekdayinput.equals("su") || weekdayinput.equals("Su") || weekdayinput.equals("SU")) {

            weekday = "Sunday";
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("You entered your weekday incorrectly.");
        }

        return weekday;
    }

}

public class GettersandREturns {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Call call1 = new Call();

        String weekday = call1.calculateweekday();
        int time = call1.calculatetime();

        System.out.println("To calculate the cost per minute of your long-distance call, we'll need some information.");
        System.out.println(
                "What hour are you planning on making the call. Minutes aren't necessary. Please only enter the hour number. (ex. 8)");
        call1.hour = input.nextInt();
        input.hasNextLine();
        System.out.println("Is the call taking place AM or PM?");
        call1.ampm = input.nextLine();
        input.hasNextLine();
        System.out.println("And what day of the week is that? Please enter weekday with only first two letters. (ex. Fr");
        call1.weekdayinput = input.nextLine();



        if (time >= 8 && time <= 11 && !weekday.equals("Saturday") && !weekday.equals("Sunday")
                || time >= 1212 && time <= 1206 && !weekday.equals("Saturday") && !weekday.equals("Sunday"))

        {
            System.out.println("Your call will charge $4.50 a minute.");
        }

        else if (time == 12 && !weekday.equals("Saturday") && !weekday.equals("Sunday")
                || time >= 1 && time < 8 && !weekday.equals("Saturday") && !weekday.equals("Sunday")
                || time > 1206 && time <= 1211 && !weekday.equals("Saturday") && !weekday.equals("Sunday")) {

            System.out.println("Your call will charge $4.00 a minute.");

        }

        else if (weekday.equals("Saturday") || weekday.equals("Sunday")){

            System.out.println("Your call will charge $2.25 a minute.");
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("You must have entered something wrong!");
        }

    }
}
```

So the idea was any call started between 8:00 Am and 6:00 PM, Monday through Friday, is billed at a rate of 4.50 per minute. Any call starting before 8:00 AM or after 6:00 PM, Monday through Friday, is billed at a rate
of 4.00 per minute. Finally, any call started on a Saturday or Sunday is charged at a rate of 2.25 per minute.

But when i run this program I get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at practice.Call.calculateweekday(GettersandREturns.java:32)
at practice.GettersandREturns.main(GettersandREturns.java:82)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Learning is hard.

Comment: *Learning is hard* candidate for the truest statement ever made.

Comment: My java is too rusty to trust any answer I could give, but I have yet to see a Java development environment without a powerful debugging utility. With a debugger you can execute the program on your terms, not the computer's. You can run the program step by step, view the results of each step, and compare them against your expectations. Where the reality and the expectations do not line up, you have found a bug either in your program or your expectations and need to resolve this before continuing.

Comment: When a program crashes, the debugger will almost always halt the program, allowing you to see how the program wound up in such a dire state. Often the crash will be deep in the bowels of a library call where you are not expected to be able to fix things. Instead operate from the assumption that the library function is correct and look at the call stack or backtrace to see what was going on in your code that may have lead up to the crash. There are bugs in libraries, but they are rare in reputable libraries, so eliminate your code before trying to understand the inner workings of the library.

Comment: You are Right The Lines after you initialize your call is where you get your Errors. Because at this Point your Call class is filled with uninitialized variables.And the Default value for a String is null which throws your error

Answer (score 1):

In your main function you are creating a new call and calling the functions of the call.

```
Call call1 = new Call();

    String weekday = call1.calculateweekday();
    int time = call1.calculatetime();
```

And at this Points you get the error, if you look at the Call class which got the following variables

```
String weekdayinput;
String weekday;
int hour;
String ampm;
int time;
```

You see that These variables aren't initialized at the beginning, for int the Default value is 0 and for a String the Defaultvalue is null (you will Encounter nullpointerexceptions sometimes when you are programming). Having a value of null not forbidden as Long as you dont try to Access this variable and that is what your functions do.

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

will be the error which

```
 if (ampm.equals("pm") || ampm.equals("PM") || ampm.equals("Pm"))
```

will throw, as your ampm or any other String you are trying to Access is null at this Point and you are trying to compare the null String with a string.

Make sure, that you initialize your Strings before you compare them with anything, for example with

```
String weekdayinput = "mo";
String weekday "mo";
int hour;
String ampm "am";
int time;
```

And you should call the functions for weekday and time after you asked for the Input.

```
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Call call1 = new Call();

    System.out.println("To calculate the cost per minute of your long-distance call, we'll need some information.");
    System.out.println(
            "What hour are you planning on making the call. Minutes aren't necessary. Please only enter the hour number. (ex. 8)");
    call1.hour = input.nextInt();
    input.hasNextLine();
    System.out.println("Is the call taking place AM or PM?");
    call1.ampm = input.nextLine();
    input.hasNextLine();
    System.out.println("And what day of the week is that? Please enter weekday with only first two letters. (ex. Fr");
    call1.weekdayinput = input.nextLine();
 String weekday = call1.calculateweekday();
    int time = call1.calculatetime();
```

And as a sidenote: You should read About switches which can replace this many if Statements.

Answer (score 1):

## Further thoughts

The [Answer by Wuttke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57263667/642706) is correct and should be accepted. Here's a few more extraneous thoughts.

Generally best to keep each class in its own .java file.

Be [careful with naming](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html). Being descriptive and specific makes your code much easier to read, review, and revise. So call your `Scanner` object something like `scanner` rather than `input`.

You can shorten some logic by converting text inputs to all uppercase or lowercase.

Your code `time > 1206 && time <= 1211` left me puzzled. I do not understand your intent.

Separate user-interface from business logic. The rules for days and times for various charges should be segregated to their own class. That makes for one place with very simple short code to read and edit when your business rules change. And business rules *always* change, eventually.

Do all the data-entry validation in your user-interface code, keeping that separated from your business logic code. Pass already-validated data to the business logic (here, the code that determines pricing). The idea is to focus on a [single responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). The business logic code should only be burdened with the job of knowing the day & time pricing scheme, not interacting with the user. Likewise, the UI code should not know about the nitty-gritty details of call-costing, but should know only enough to validate data-entry.

Instead of the series of `if` statements, use `switch` as shown in the [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).

Use smart objects rather than dumb strings or mere integers, whenever possible. Java offers the [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) [enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html), so use those seven pre-defined objects rather than clumsy strings. Likewise, we have a [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html) class for time-of-day without date and without time zone.

Java has strong features for localizing. So no need to hard-code things like dollar sign and name of day-of-week.

Resources such as a `Scanner` should be closed when you are done using them. The [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax automates this chore.

## Example code

Here is some example code. Not meant for production, not tested. But should prove interesting to someone learning Java.

In real work I would:

- Do more error-checking, like checking for the scanner being closed.
- Pull out each of the parsing sections (hour, AM/PM, and day-of-week) into subroutines (named private methods).
- Replace the conventional `switch` statement to the new [simplified `switch` statement](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/354) being previewed in Java 12 & Java 13.
- Give the user an exit option on every prompt, like `q` to quit.
- Use [unit testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) to verify logic.

First, the business logic portion.

```
package work.basil.example;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;

public class CallCostEstimator
{
    private Set < DayOfWeek > weekdays = EnumSet.of ( DayOfWeek.MONDAY , DayOfWeek.TUESDAY , DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY , DayOfWeek.THURSDAY , DayOfWeek.FRIDAY );
    LocalTime daytimeStart = LocalTime.of ( 8 , 0 );
    LocalTime daytimeStop = LocalTime.of ( 18 , 0 );

    BigDecimal weekday_day_rate = new BigDecimal ( "4.5" );
    BigDecimal weekday_night_rate = new BigDecimal ( "4.0" );
    BigDecimal weekend_rate = new BigDecimal ( "2.25" );

    public BigDecimal estimate ( LocalTime localTime , DayOfWeek dayOfWeek )
    {
        Objects.requireNonNull ( localTime );
        Objects.requireNonNull ( dayOfWeek );

        boolean isWeekday = ( weekdays.contains ( dayOfWeek ) );
        boolean isDaytimeHours = ( ! localTime.isBefore ( this.daytimeStart ) ) && ( localTime.isBefore ( this.daytimeStop ) );

        // Determine price slot
        BigDecimal result = null;
        if ( ! isWeekday )
        {
            result = this.weekend_rate;   // In other cases we would make a copy before returning an object stored within this class. But `BigDecimal` is immutable, so not necessary.
        } else
        { // Else is weekday.
            if ( isDaytimeHours )
            {
                result = this.weekday_day_rate;
            } else
            {
                result = this.weekday_night_rate;
            }
        }
        if ( Objects.isNull ( result ) ) // Should not be possible if our cascade of `if` statements is complete and correct. Defensive programming requires that we check.
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException ( "Failed to find a price slot." );
        }
        return result;
    }


}
```

And the user-interface portion.

```
package work.basil.example;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.FormatStyle;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.util.*;

public class CallCostEstimateConsole
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        CallCostEstimateConsole app = new CallCostEstimateConsole ();
        app.engageUser ();
    }


    public void engageUser ( )
    {
        // Use try-with-resources syntax to auto-close the scanner.
        try (
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner ( System.in ) ;
        )
        {

            System.out.println ( "To calculate the cost per minute of your long-distance call, we'll need some information." );
            Integer hour = null;
            while ( Objects.isNull ( hour ) )
            {
                System.out.println ( "What hour are you planning on making the call?  Minutes aren't necessary. Please only enter the hour number, 1-12 for 12-hour clock. (ex. 8)" );
                try
                {
                    int input = scanner.nextInt ();
                    if ( ( input < 1 ) || ( input > 12 ) )
                    {
                        System.out.println ( "Hour must be from 1 to 12." );
                    } else
                    {
                        hour = input;
                    }
                } catch ( InputMismatchException e )
                {
                    System.out.println ( "Error: Enter a digits only, for a number from 1 to 12. " );
                }
            }

            String amPm = null;
            while ( Objects.isNull ( amPm ) )
            {
                System.out.println ( "Is the call taking place AM or PM? (type either AM or PM, or am or pm)" );
                String input = scanner.next ();
                input = input.toUpperCase ();
                if ( input.equals ( "AM" ) || ( input.equals ( "PM" ) ) )
                {
                    amPm = input;
                } else
                {
                    System.out.println ( "You typed something other than AM or PM." );
                    continue;
                }
                // Tweak inputs for 12-hour to 24-hour conversion.
                if ( amPm.equals ( "AM" ) && ( hour == 12 ) )
                {
                    hour = 0;
                }
            }
            // If 1 PM through 11 PM, add 12 hours for 24-hour time.
            hour = ( amPm.equals ( "PM" ) & ( hour < 12 ) ) ? ( hour + 12 ) : hour;  // Ternary statement. A compact alternative to an `if` statement.
            LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.of ( hour , 0 );

            DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = null;
            while ( Objects.isNull ( dayOfWeek ) )
            {
                System.out.println ( "And what day of the week is that? Please enter weekday with only first two letters. (ex. Fr)" );
                try
                {
                    String input = scanner.next ().toLowerCase ();
                    if ( input.isEmpty () )
                    {
                        System.out.println ( "You did not type any characters. " );
                        continue; // Break-out to continue on to the next loop.
                    }

                    // Parsing logic.
                    switch ( input )
                    {
                        case "mo":
                            dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.MONDAY;
                            break;
                        case "tu":
                            dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.TUESDAY;
                            break;
                        case "we":
                            dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY;
                            break;
                        case "th":
                            dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.THURSDAY;
                            break;
                        case "fr":
                            dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.FRIDAY;
                            break;
                        case "sa":
                            dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.SATURDAY;
                            break;
                        case "su":
                            dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.SUNDAY;
                            break;
                        default:
                            String message = "You did not type a 2-letter day-of-week code as expected. (Mo, Tu, We, Th, Fr, Sa, Su)";
                            throw new IllegalStateException ( message );
                    }
                } catch ( InputMismatchException e )
                {
                    System.out.println ( "Error: Enter a digits only, for a number from 1 to 12. " );
                }
            }

            // Calculate result.
            CallCostEstimator estimator = new CallCostEstimator ();
            BigDecimal estimate = estimator.estimate ( localTime , dayOfWeek );

            // Report result.
            String output = NumberFormat.getInstance ( Locale.US ).getCurrencyInstance ().format ( estimate );
            DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime ( FormatStyle.SHORT ).withLocale ( Locale.US );
            String dow = dayOfWeek.getDisplayName ( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.US );
            String message = "Your call at " + localTime.format ( f ) + " on " + dow + " will cost per minute: " + output;
            System.out.println ( message );

        }
    }
}
```

Example run.

```
To calculate the cost per minute of your long-distance call, we'll need some information.
What hour are you planning on making the call?  Minutes aren't necessary. Please only enter the hour number, 1-12 for 12-hour clock. (ex. 8)
1
Is the call taking place AM or PM? (type either AM or PM, or am or pm)
am
And what day of the week is that? Please enter weekday with only first two letters. (ex. Fr)
mo
Your call at 1:00 AM on Monday will cost per minute: $4.00
```